# Trigger PHP with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP process that get's a user's IP address, the page they are on, screen resolution and Date/Time on my website.

I want to put a line of code on my other website such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/tracker.js"></script>
```

In this JavaScript file, it would post the information to a file called tracker.php which then processes the information to put in the database.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to achieve it.

Comment: you tagged the question with AJAX, so maybe use that?

Comment: I tagged the question with AJAX, because I heard that's a way it can be done, but I don't know AJAX too well.

Comment: well i could spend a few hours writing an ajax tutorial for you, or you could google it.

Comment: I'm not asking someone to make anything for me, I'm just hoping someone could point me in the direction?

Comment: i did AJAX AJAX and AJAX. get it?

Comment: I would like to add that this question is tagged with `CORS`, so any answer should address server configuration for the "other website" if there's going to be a POST request.

Comment: I have managed to come across a solution which I would post, but I am not able to answer the question until after 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're asking how to send an asynchronous request for tracker.php, AKA AJAX. W3 schools has a guide on that here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

The IP address and Date/Time can be easily gotten without passing any information down from the website. If you want to pass information such as the page they are on and the resolution of their viewing area, then one very easy way to do it is to pass URL variables.

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","tracker.php?WindowWidth=" + window.innerWidth +"&WindowHeight=" + window.innerHeight + "&Page=" + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) ,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

These variables will be loaded into the tracker.php as the array `$_GET`

```
$Width = $_GET["WindowWidth"];
$Height = $_GET["WindowHeight"];
$Page = $_GET["WindowPage"];
```

There are more elegant solutions, such as `$_POST` which allows far more information to be passed down in a single request, or 1x1 tracking images. The Page they are on can also be acquired by using `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` on tracker.php.

Comment: This is the solution I also came to but instead used POST.